# Proving that all monomorphisms in the category of sets are equalizers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I am trying to prove that all monomorphisms (injective functions) in the category of sets, are equalizers.

The more exact claim I want to prove is that if $m:A \to B$ is mono, then $(m,A)$ is an equalizer for the pair of functions $\varphi_m: B \to \Omega$ and $Tt_B:B \to \Omega$, where $T:\mathbf{1} \to \Omega$ is the constant element "true" of the subobject classifier and $t_B: B \to \mathbf{1}$ is the unique function into the terminal object $\mathbf{1}$. $\varphi_m$ is the characteristic function of $m$.

I have tried the following but I am a little unsure whether it is correct:

Since $\varphi_m$ is a characteristic function for $m$ it follows that $\varphi_m m = T t_A = T(t_B m)=(T t_B)m$. So $m$ equalizes the functions. Letting $x:T \to B$ be such that $(T t_B) x = \varphi_m x$ it follows that since $\varphi_m$ is a characteristic function that $x \in m$, and hence $x=m \bar{x}$ for a unique $\bar{x}:T \to A$ since $m$ is mono.

Is this the correct way to prove it?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, actually this holds in any topos and the proof is similar.

You use the pullback square associated to $m$ by the definition of $\Omega$ (subobject classifier), and any arrow that equalizes the two arrows mentioned makes the pullback square commute, which in turn implies that it can be factorized through $m$.

However I am unsure why you said $x: T\to B$ when you defined $T$ to be the "true" arrow.

The proof should thus go like this :

Let $\chi_m$ be the character of $m: A\to B$, $\top_B$ the true arrow from $B$, i.e. $\top\circ !_B$ (where $\top : 1\to \Omega$, and $!_B : B\to 1$). Thus we have the following commuting diagram : 
[image]

Thus if there is an arrow $f: x\to B$ that also equalizes those two arrows, the computations on the side show that this diagram commutes : 
[image]

(Where $!_x = !_B \circ f$ due to the universal property of $1$)
Since the square is a pullback square by definition, we get an arrow $g: x\to A$ with $m\circ g = f$. But this arrow is necessarily unique since $m$ is mono. Therefore $(A,m)$ is an equalizer of the pair $(\top_B, \chi_M)$

As you can see, this works in any topos, so in particular it works in $Set$